# How do I compare 2 rows with a unique ID and flag specific columns with different data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

How do I compare rows from 2 dataframe and flag changes in a different columns. I have 2 dataframes: df1 (historic data) containing data that was acquired in Jan. I have updated data received on Aug 1. The updated df2 has all old records with updates and new records.

I need to create a df3 and flag all the old records if important date was updated like  Grade, math_level, Sci_level, Eng_level. Non-important data changes need not be flagged ( Address) but need to be included. If a record had any updates important or not, both old and new records should be in the df3. if a record had no changes then only one record should be in the final df3.

I am using Python Pandas and I am absolutely lost at this point.

This is existing data I have

```
data1 = {'Name': ['Andy Spencer', 'Jennifer Thomson', 'John Smith', 'Mary Ray','Rob Hay'],
        'ID': [876, 198, 134, 345,673],
       'location': ['KS', 'NY','MA','KS','GA'],
        'address': ['5th street', '80 Cream Ave','1 apple street','34 Lemon St','45 Main Lane'],
        'grade': [7, 5, 5, 6,5],
        'math_level': ['Intermediate', 'Intermediate','Expert','Beginner','Intermediate'],
        'Sci_level': ['Intermediate', 'Beginner','Intermediate','Intermediate','Beginner'],
        'Eng_level': ['Beginner', 'Beginner','Intermediate','Expert','Expert'],
        'Updated': ['1/1/2022', '1/1/2022','1/1/2022','1/1/2022','1/1/2022'],
        'Change_Flag': [np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df1
```

|  | Name | ID | location | address | grade | math_level | Sci_level | Eng_level | Updated | Change_Flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Andy Spencer | 876 | KS | 5th street | 7 | Intermediate | Intermediate | Beginner | 1/1/2022 | NaN |
| 1 | Jennifer Thomson | 198 | NY | 80 Cream Ave | 5 | Intermediate | Beginner | Beginner | 1/1/2022 | NaN |
| 2 | John Smith | 134 | MA | 1 apple street | 5 | Expert | Intermediate | Intermediate | 1/1/2022 | NaN |
| 3 | Mary Ray | 345 | KS | 34 Lemon St | 6 | Beginner | Intermediate | Expert | 1/1/2022 | NaN |
| 4 | Rob Hay | 673 | GA | 45 Main Lane | 5 | Intermediate | Beginner | Expert | 1/1/2022 | NaN |

This is the new data. The data does not have the Change_Flag column, this was created in df1

```
data2 = {'Name': ['Alan Cooper','Andy Spencer', 'Jennifer Thomson', 'John Smith','Maggie Holland', 'Mary Ray','Rob Hay'],
        'ID': [544,876, 198, 134,987 ,345,673],
       'location': ['MA','KS', 'NY','MA','GA','KS','GA'],
        'address': ['78 York Street','5th street', '80 Cream Ave','1 apple street','766 Austin Lane','34 Lemon St','45 Main Lane'],
        'grade': [6,7,6, 5,5,7,5],
        'math_level':['Intermediate', 'Super-Expert','Expert','Expert','Super-Expert','Intermediate','Intermediate'],
        'Sci_level': ['Intermediate', 'Expert','Beginner','Intermediate','Beginner','Intermediate','Beginner'],
        'Eng_level': ['Intermediate', 'Intermediate','Beginner','Intermediate', 'Intermediate','Expert','Expert'],
        'Updated': ['1/8/2022', '1/8/2022','1/8/2022','1/8/2022','1/8/2022','1/8/2022','1/8/2022']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
df2
```

|  | Name | ID | location | address | grade | math_level | Sci_level | Eng_level | Updated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Alan Cooper | 544 | MA | 78 York Street | 6 | Intermediate | Intermediate | Intermediate | 1/8/2022 |
| 1 | Andy Spencer | 876 | KS | 5th street | 7 | Super-Expert | Expert | Intermediate | 1/8/2022 |
| 2 | Jennifer Thomson | 198 | NY | 80 Cream Ave | 6 | Expert | Beginner | Beginner | 1/8/2022 |
| 3 | John Smith | 134 | MA | 1 apple street | 5 | Expert | Intermediate | Intermediate | 1/8/2022 |
| 4 | Maggie Holland | 987 | GA | 766 Austin Lane | 5 | Super-Expert | Beginner | Intermediate | 1/8/2022 |
| 5 | Mary Ray | 345 | KS | 34 Lemon St | 7 | Intermediate | Intermediate | Expert | 1/8/2022 |
| 6 | Rob Hay | 673 | GA | 45 Main Lane | 5 | Intermediate | Beginner | Expert | 1/8/2022 |

```
df1.drop(['Updated','Change_Flag'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df2.drop('Updated', axis=1, inplace=True)
diff_dfs = pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False).reset_index(drop=True)
diff_dfs
```

This is what I get. How do I create a Change_Flag column and append this data to df1?

|  | Name | ID | location | address | grade | math_level | Sci_level | Eng_level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Andy Spencer | 876 | KS | 5th street | 7 | Intermediate | Intermediate | Beginner |
| 1 | Jennifer Thomson | 198 | NY | 80 Cream Ave | 5 | Intermediate | Beginner | Beginner |
| 2 | Mary Ray | 345 | KS | 34 Lemon St | 6 | Beginner | Intermediate | Expert |
| 3 | Alan Cooper | 544 | MA | 78 York Street | 6 | Intermediate | Intermediate | Intermediate |
| 4 | Andy Spencer | 876 | KS | 5th street | 7 | Super-Expert | Expert | Intermediate |
| 5 | Jennifer Thomson | 198 | NY | 80 Cream Ave | 6 | Expert | Beginner | Beginner |
| 6 | Maggie Holland | 987 | GA | 766 Austin Lane | 5 | Super-Expert | Beginner | Intermediate |
| 7 | Mary Ray | 345 | KS | 34 Lemon St | 7 | Intermediate | Intermediate | Expert |

I want a df3 like this new & updated data appended to df1

|  | name | ID | location | address | grade | math_level | Sci_level | Eng_level | Updated on | Change_Flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Alan Cooper | 544 | MA | 78 York Street | 6 | Intermediate | Intermediate | Intermediate | 1/8/2022 | NaN |
| 1 | Andy Spencer | 876 | KS | 5th street | 7 | Intermediate | Intermediate | Beginner | 1/1/2022 | NaN |
| 2 | Andy Spencer | 876 | KS | 5th street | 7 | Super -Expert | Expert | Intermediate | 1/8/2022 | Yes |
| 3 | Jennifer Thomson | 198 | NY | 80 Cream Ave | 5 | Intermediate | Beginner | Beginner | 1/1/2022 | NaN |
| 4 | Jennifer Thomson | 198 | NY | 9th West Street | 6 | Expert | Beginner | Beginner | 1/8/2022 | Yes |
| 5 | John Smith | 134 | MA | 1 apple street, MA | 5 | Expert | Intermediate | Intermediate | 1/1/2022 | NaN |
| 6 | John Smith | 134 | MA | 1 Berry Lane | 5 | Expert | Intermediate | Intermediate | 1/8/2022 | NaN |
| 7 | Maggie Holland | 987 | GA | 766 Austin Lane | 5 | Super -Expert | Beginner | Intermediate | 1/8/2022 | NaN |
| 8 | Mary Ray | 345 | KS | 34 Lemon St | 6 | Beginner | Intermediate | Expert | 1/1/2022 | NaN |
| 9 | Mary Ray | 345 | KS | 34 Lemon St | 7 | Intermediate | Intermediate | Expert | 1/8/2022 | Yes |
| 10 | Rob Hay | 673 | GA | 45 Main Lane | 5 | Intermediate | Beginner | Expert | 1/1/2022 | NaN |

Comment: I edited my code and added the code to create the dataframes

Answer (score 1):

I think you can solve this problem by [concatenating](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) both datasets and after that [dropping all duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) - if the row has not changed they are going to be duplicates!

It would be something like this:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
df_no_duplicates = df.drop_duplicates()
```

You can also specify the subset argument in `drop_duplicates` to drop by specific columns.

Comment: i do that but how do I select few columns for the code to check if the data has changed